# How to break line if <span> running out the toolbar in angular8

Tags: css, angular

I have this code which bring value and the value description nearby. I need that if the length of the  value is long, it won't run out of the toolbar

```js
     <div class="tool-bar">
          <ul class="pair-list">
            <li class="blue-box-field" *ngFor="let param of data.parameters">
              <span>{{ param.paramTypeHebName }}</span>
              <span>{{ param.valueHebName }}</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image: the running out]

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```css
.tool-bar{
overflow: hidden
}
```

to your css and that should fix it.
If you just want the line to break try adding following class to the line that you want to break:

```css
.span-break{
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: isn't that what you want ? "if the length of the value is long, it won't run out of the toolbar" ?

Comment: yes but I mean not to hide the value, it should break the line

Comment: Updated my answer give the second point a shot, good luck. If that does not help create a pen on code pen so people can help you with your exact problem.

Comment: its still hidden it

Comment: Please create a codepen or minimal reproducible example where your css is included

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232248/discussion-between-priyank-trivedi-and-kate).